# Is it possible to make onClick event on content of text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display XML data in a textarea and trying to make onClick event on content of textarea. For eg.

> < textarea >Hello Web, This is simple html page.< / textarea >

Here I want to make onClick event on each 'i' character.

Please help me on this.

Comment: No you can't, on the whole for the `<textarea>` you can do!! and is there any specific reason you doing it?

Comment: @yashhy can't do that with a textarea, but you can make a div contenteditable and paste the content from your XML, while making all "i" characters anchors, style them and make functionality properly there.

Comment: @yashhy so can i display XML content in some other element?

Comment: @Raj Like ? Can you prepare a fiddle to illustrate your point ?

Comment: @Burimi Yeah!! but its a long process. How abt Sergei answer over here?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov I found solution(using caret position in textarea).Anyway thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't however you can use a little workaround. Add onclik event, and check caret position in the textarea, then you know between what characters it's located.

How to get it described here:

[Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)

```
  textarea.onmouseup = textarea.onkeyup = function () {
    console.log(getCaret(textarea));
  };
```

it returns and index for textarea value string...

here is fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/ydLKF/1/